# How do I fix the errors I get after removing the comment field from a content type?

Tags: comments

After I removed the comment field from the user interface, and uninstalled the Comments module, I can't open any *Article* node.

In the Drupal log, I find this message.

> InvalidArgumentException: Field comment is unknown. in Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->getTranslatedField() (line 580 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityBase.php).
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->get("comment") (Line: 17)
>   gavias_sanbro_preprocess_node(Array, "node", Array) (Line: 287)
>   Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render("node", Array) (Line: 437)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 195)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, ) (Line: 226)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent{closure}() (Line: 582)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 227)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare(Array, Object,
>   Object) (Line: 117)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 90)
>   Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object, "kernel.view", Object)
>   call_user_func(Array, Object, "kernel.view", Object) (Line: 111)
>   Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch("kernel.view", Object) (Line: 156)
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 99)
>   Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 78)
>   Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
>   Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 657)
>   Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: This is the error from apache webserver :  Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "Field comment is unknown." at /var/www/eierc/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityBase.php line 580

Comment: Drupal log message after i enabled verbose: https://pastebin.com/s3wPwhYx

Comment: Please always add such information to your question instead of pasting it into the comments. This will help others to suggest steps to perform for solving your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your error stacktrace:

Check function `gavias_sanbro_preprocess_node()` (Line: 287 in your `gavias_sanbro.theme` theme file).

This preprocessing function obviously tries to access the `comment` field without checking, whether it exists. As you uninstalled the field, it is causing your exception.

You may comment out, remove, or alter the code accordingly.